# remove border bottom in ion header

Tags: html, css, border, ionic-framework

I have a problem trying to remove ion header border bottom in my ionic app

[image: you could see my ionic header with border here]

Here is the code of `tab-home.html`:

```
                <ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
            <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-transparent" >
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon ion-ios7-settings">
            </button>
            <div class="title">&nbsp;</div>
            <h1 class="title">proximiti</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <!--<ion-nav-bar class="bar-transparent">
            </ion-nav-bar>-->
            <ion-pane ng-controller="CardsCtrl">
            <!--<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon ion-navicon"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>-->
            <td-cards>
            <td-card ng-repeat="card in cards" on-destroy="cardDestroyed($index)" on-swipe-left="cardSwipedLeft($index)" on-swipe-right="cardSwipedRight($index)" on-partial-swipe="cardPartialSwipe(amt)" class="card-{{card.index}}" ng-controller="CardCtrl">
            <div class="image">
            <!--<div class="yes-text" ng-style="leftTextOpacity">LIKE</div>-->
            <img ng-src="{{card.image}}">
            <!--<div class="no-text" ng-style="rightTextOpacity">NOPE</div>-->
            </div>
            </td-card>
            </td-cards>
            </ion-pane>
            </ion-view>
```

As you can see here the part we're interested in:

```
                <ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
            <ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-transparent" >
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon ion-ios7-settings">
            </button>
            <div class="title">&nbsp;</div>
            <h1 class="title">proximiti</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
```

I tried everything (in the browser i don't see this border!), but nothing to change it!
Anyone could help me trying to find the way to delete that border? 
N.B. : also tried to edit ionic.css and changed only in the browser.

**EDIT: And it should be hidden only in this view, so where the class is bar-transparent**

Comment: You ever find a resolution to this? Having a similar issue.

Comment: Did you try adding the style: background-image: none; border-bottom: none ?

Comment: I am using sidemenu in my app and wanted to make the header transparent! can you explain how did you made your header transparent? i am also having the border issue :( its been weeks.. have mercy !

Comment: @MilanMaharjan you can see how I did in the answer I've accepted.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In **ionic 2/3** border will be removed by using **ionic-header no-border**.

```
<ion-header no-border> </ion-header>
```

In **ionic 5** border will be removed by using **class="ion-no-border"**.

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border"></ion-header>
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it uses ionic helper classes.

Answer (score 34):

No problem,

Just add this to your custom CSS:

```
.bar-header {
    border: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, but I don't understand why..can you give some explanation?

Comment: If the snippet doesn't work (as it did for me) try to add !important; to the background-image and border-bottom properties.

Comment: With Ionic 2+ the accepted answer should be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064058/3397345

Answer (score 17):

For ionic 5, it should be

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border"></ion-header>
```

Answer (score 8):

@BenNov answer doesn't work for me.

this is what i did to remove ion-nav-bar bottom border

```
.bar {
    background-size: 100% 0px;
}
```

*I'm working with ionic-1.0.0-rc.4*

Comment: yes. this is what i did to remove ion-nav-bar bottom border

Comment: This does not remove the border, just changes the background placement. Probably the border and your background are the same, but the border is still there and it's height is still accounted for.

Answer (score 7):

For Ionic 5, this worked for me:

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border"></ion-header>
```

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:  Using overflow CSS property

```
ion-header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Option 2: Using the no-border proterty of

```
<ion-header no-border><ion-header>
```

Comment: Adding overflow: hidden is the only solution which works for me in Ionic 4.

Answer (score 0):

This removed the border between the header and tabs for me on ionic 1.1.0

```
.bar-header {
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like that way...

Give **ion-toolbar** child of ion-header a class like "headerMain" and apply css below.

css:

```
.headerMain {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```